# Plots with "no marks" have marks in references

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot some functions without marks and reference them in my text - the problem is that in the text there are some random marks and i can't turn them off somehow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
plotl/.style={blue,no marks,ultra thick,domain=-2:2,samples=50},
plotd/.style={red,no marks,ultra thick,domain=-2:2,samples=50}
}
\begin{document}
Text blablbalbal \ref{plot:probH} blablalbalba \ref{plot:probL}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,height= 200pt,legend pos=north east,xlabel = $E_x$, ylabel=$p_x$]
\addplot+[plotl]{0.15*exp(-x/0.5)/(0.5*sinh(4)};\addlegendentry{$T = 0.5$}\label{plot:probL}
\addplot+[plotd]{0.15*exp(-x/4)/(4*sinh(0.5)};\addlegendentry{$T = 4.0$}\label{plot:probH}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `+` after the `\addplot`.

Comment: thanks a lot.
you could make an answer out of this (i think the question hasn't been asked before - at least searching didn't yield useful results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `+` after `\addplot`. The `+` indicates that you want to keep the normal cycle list options (including the markers) active in addition to the plot options which you specify in `[...]`.